# Can I change only the angle of a linear gradient in css3 on hover?

Tags: css

So I have a linear gradient on an element, and I want to change the gradients angle to be upside down when I hover the element without writing all the rules again.Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could make it DRYer by using [`sass`](http://sass-lang.com/) and mixins.

```css
@mixin gradient($angle) {
    background: linear-gradient($angle , rgb(23,125,250) 28%, rgb(0,0,0) 80%);
}

#grad {
    @import gradient("bottom");
}

#grad:hover {
    @import gradient("right");
}
```

Comment: was going to update my answer to add CSS frameworks solutions, aborting the update thanks to this. nice one, +1.

Comment: I apreciate your answers, but sass is only a preprocessor, but the loaded css will still be big, if I have many gradients with many hovers.I suppose it can not be done the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

why not? simply create a rule for the `hover` state by specifying a pseudo class in your CSS:

```css
#grad {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(23,125,250) 28%, rgb(0,0,0) 80%);
}
#grad:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(right , rgb(23,125,250) 28%, rgb(0,0,0) 80%);
}
```

if you wish to follow the DRY principle, create those rules as helper classes, than attach and detach them to the element. here's an example using jQuery:

**CSS:**

```css
.grad {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(23,125,250) 28%, rgb(0,0,0) 80%);
}
.grad-rotated {
    background-image: linear-gradient(right , rgb(23,125,250) 28%, rgb(0,0,0) 80%);
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$('.grad').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('grad', false).toggleClass('grad-rotated', true);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('grad', true).toggleClass('grad-rotated', false);
    }
);
```

**References:**

- [jQuery's `hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [`linear-gradient` on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient)
- [a nice, easy to use, CSS gradients generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

***Note:** for convenience, only the basic form of the `linear-gradient` property value is shown here, to provide cross-browser compatibility, add the vendor-specific prefixed property values (e.g. `-o-linear-gradient`, `-moz-linear-gradient`).*

***Disclaimer:** as user-agents will render CSS more efficiently, in general it's best to prefer CSS based solutions over JS based.*

Comment: +1 on correct answer. I have to disagree, though, on the JS solution, as I find using JS where CSS is appropriate bad practice.

Comment: i agree, CSS will render much faster, is more elegant etc. updating my post on this. thanks.

Comment: I would like to emphasize this part "without writing all the rules again".Because of the vendor properties, this can take a lot of file length.So I want something like this:selector {background:linear-gradient:...} selector:hover {background:linear-gradient-angle:90%}

Comment: with helper classes in the CSS, you'll only have to create each rule permutation once.